# How to perform case insensitive title search in Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I wanted to search in Google Documents for a title provided by user.This search should be case insensitive as the user may not have the exact title.
I am doing search as below

```
param = {"q":"title = 'my test file'"}
files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
```

I don't get any results , but there is file with title as "My Test File"
I do not see any information in the Google Documentation about case insensitive seacrh, [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters)

But if I search as below , I get one result

```
param = {"q":"title = 'My Test File'"}
files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
```

Comment: would param = {"q":"lower(title)= 'my test file'"} work?

Comment: Nope , did not work, says , "Invalid query"

Comment: For this you can try contains operator instead. It is not case sensitive. However the contains operator only performs prefix matching for a title. For example, the title "HelloWorld" would match for title contains 'Hello' but not title contains 'World'. Tried to make the search with contains operator and it did list the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can make it work with contains query.

Comment: Np. Glad that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can try contains operator instead.

It is not case sensitive. However the contains operator only performs prefix matching for a title. For example, the title "HelloWorld" would match for title contains 'Hello' but not title contains 'World'. Tried to make the search with contains operator and it did list the file.